# DynamicData Partial Class not working

Tags: dynamic-data, partial-classes

Partial class not working with Dynamic Data.  I'm not using the default dynamicdata project type, but rather just using it on a control-by-control basis

Comment: I'm answering my own question straight after posting it, because it took me ages to find the solution, so I thought I'd try and save anyone searching some time.

An easy fix, but not obvious.

You need to make sure your dbml and partial class are in the SAME namespace.

grr..

here's where I found it:
http://squenchy.com/when-adding-partial-classes-to-dynamic-data-doesnt-work.aspx

Comment: well SO wont let me answer the question for the next 8hrs, so  the answer is in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question straight after posting it, because it took me ages to find the solution, so I thought I'd try and save anyone searching some time. An easy fix, but not obvious. You need to make sure your dbml and partial class are in the SAME namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.  The namespace wasn't my issue.  After 2 hours of getting nowhere, I finally found the setting that fixed the issue for me.  The .cs class file containing my partial classes had a Build Action of Content.  I changed Build Action to Compile, and the customizations worked.

In Solution Explorer, right click your .cs file (the one with your partial classes), choose Properties, select Compile under Build Action.

Hope this helps.